# Syntax Error Ruby Simple form dependent fields gem Haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, field, simple-form

Im a rails newbie trying to implement the depending fields gem. I have been following this tutorial but keep getting syntax erros.

I am Ruby Haml FYI

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dependent-fields-rails/0.4.2

I have only tried whats mentioned the the tutorial, i get the following errors

app/views/houses/_form.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
app/views/houses/_form.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
app/views/houses/new.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_houses_new_html_haml___583738311_56256552'

Here is my houses_form.erb.haml

```
= simple_form_for @house do |f|
  = f.input :doorno, :label => "House No or Name:"
  = f.input :house_title, :label => "Street Name:"
  = f.input :postcode, :label => "Post Code:"
  = f.input :description, :label => "Description:"
  = f.input :price, as: :currency, :inline_label => "Price:"
  = f.input :occupied, inline_label: 'Tick if the Property Occupied'
  .js-dependent-fields{data-checkbox-id='house_occupied' data-checkbox- 
   value='true'}
    = f.association :tenant, :label => "Tenant Name:"
  = f.button :submit, class: "button"
```

The tenant field only to show if the occupied box is ticked

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require underscore
//= require dependent-fields

$(document).ready(function() {
DependentFields.bind()
}
```

Tried changing {} to [], still similar syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `{}` in your`.js-dependent-fields` call. Try changing `{}` to `[]`.

Comment: i tried this but still no luck, got similar syntax errors app/views/houses/_form.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']'
app/views/houses/_form.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'
app/views/houses/_form.html.haml:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'